# Is it possible to install multiple Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework on client server?

Tags: .net, iis, crystal-reports

We have to maintain two version of a .NET app in the same server.

They have two different sites created in IIS

Current version uses:

- SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework (13.0.32.4286)

While the older version:

- Version (13.0.23.2819).

Is there any way I can use both in the same machine ?

Comment: Since Crystal Reports 9, each major can be installed on the same machine, but only one version per major can be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the older app (using SP23) to use the newer runtime (SP32) by creating/editing the exe.config or web config file.

Here is an old example. Adjust it to fit your needs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>    
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Shared" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Web" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonControls" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>    
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Prompting" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>  
</runtime>
</configuration>
```